# A Component changing its props?

Tags: reactjs

So, I want my component to render only when I do it (eg. when it is clicked.) . I don't want it to re-render when its props changes.

So, my idea was to have the parent pass a wasClicked='true' prop, when it is clicked, which I change to 'false' once it is rendered and have a condition in the render body to only render when wasClicked is true.

How is this possible?

Comment: Welcome!  Can you elaborate a bit more on your specific problem?  You said that you don't want the component to re-render when props change, but your proposed solution involves passing prop in to cause the re-render

Answer (score 0):

With class components, you can decide if you want to update component with a lifecycle method called [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate). With a functional component, you can decide if the component should update with [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

Answer (score 0):

That should be easy, lets say this is a simple component that only renders when wasClicked is true:

simpleComponent.js:

```
import react from "react";

const SimpleComponent = (props) => {
  return <p> some text </p>;
};

export default SimpleComponent;
```

App.js;

```
import react from "react";
import SimpleComponent from "./simpleComponent.js";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      wasClicked: false, //this is the state for wasClicked
    };
  }
  //this is the function that changes wasClicked to true when the component is clicked
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ wasClicked: true });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.wasClicked && ( //this will only render SimpleComponent when wasClicked is true
          <SimpleComponent
            onClick={this.handleClick}
            wasClicked={this.state.wasClicked}
          />
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Hope this was helpful and clear, thanks